# Finding Taylor expansion that fits the series I have

Tags: mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics

Given the potential $\phi = \alpha/r^n$, I want to find the second virial coefficient of my system. My integration limits are from some cut-off length $D$ because the particles don't experience a self-force.
This was my procedure:
$$B_2(T) = -2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{-\beta \alpha /r^n} -1) r^2 dr \\
    = -2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} r^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{r^{kn} k!} dr \\
    = -2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^kr^{-kn+2}}{ k!} dr \\
    = -2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{D}^{\infty}  (-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^kr^{-kn+2}}{ k!} dr \\
    = -2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{ k!} \int_{D}^{\infty} r^{-kn+2}dr \\ 
    = -2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{ k!} \cdot \frac{r^{-kn+3}}{-kn+3} \bigg|_{D} ^{\infty} \\
    = 2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{ k!} \cdot \frac{D^{-kn+3}}{-kn+3}$$

My question is, is there a well-defined function with a Maclaurin series defined as the last line?

Comment: I'd start by non dimensionalizing the integral, setting ${r^n \over (\alpha \beta)}= y^n$.

Comment: okay, but i mean i am getting the same form after i make substitution... @user619894

Comment: For starters you see the that integral converges for $D \rightarrow 0$ So any expansion you get must be independent of $D$ when $D$ vanishes. Also, note that expanding $e^{-1 \over y^n}$ near zero is not a good idea (essential singularity). I think that you should split the integral into at least 2 pieces, $[0,\epsilon) ; [\epsilon,\infty)$  and ignore the $\exp$ in the first range, and expand in the second. A clever choice of $\epsilon$ should allow you to match.

Comment: Mathematica gives $\frac{2}{3} \pi  \left((\beta \alpha) ^{3/n} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{n-3}{n},D^{-n} \beta \alpha \right)\right)+D^3 \left(e^{\beta \alpha  \left(-D^{-n}\right)}-1\right)\right)$